# my form is not showing up properly on desktop view

Tags: css, forms, mobile, desktop

I've made some changes to my mobile version and since then my desktop version has been affected causing the css to push everything to the left I'm not sure why. here is the link for now until I can get the code entered.

[link here](http://www.munroprinting.com/contactform.php)

Comment: cant see the problem. can you point it ?

Comment: yes on desktop view it should be centered completely but the forms fieldset for some reason it stretched wide across the screen.

Comment: id like to have it completely centered in the middle of the page

Answer (score 0):

You have mistake in class name, look video https://www.screenmailer.com/v/7aagE5AeVg1tDqQ

Comment: well now that you've solved that issue for me maybe you could help me figure out how to get the fieldset at the normal size, or maybe you could help me put the other input fields to the right of the fieldset but I don't know if that'd effect the mobile version.

Comment: do I just copy this into my files I'm guessing?

Comment: whatever I just put into my files just messed up both of my forms and I don't know it's still affecting it I just deleted it

Comment: could really use your help because now neither of my forms are working and I cant seem to figure out what's going on

Comment: I've gone through all of the code for css and the form I don't know what I changed but neither form is showing up on the page

Comment: I've figured It out lol accidentally moved the folder into another didn't realize it until looking into the webroot file and seeing it wasn't there

Comment: @user7436497 I can help you only with the page layout

Comment: by the way that also didn't help, all it did was take away the fieldset surrounding my input boxes

Comment: @user7436497 Show how you did, make screenshot how you want, give me more info